# Outlook ignoring auto hide and showing ribbon after sleep/hibernate

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, sleep, hibernate, ribbon

When using Outlook I have the ribbon completely hidden with the "Auto Hide" feature. I like this as it frees up an inch of screen space for other information.

Recently (within the last 3-6 months), Outlook has developed a quirk. Despite the fact that I always use Outlook with the ribbon hidden, and that I almost never use any of the ribbon functions, Outlook has started showing the ribbon at startup. This happens when the computer boots, and it happens whenever the laptop woken up from sleep or hibernate mode.

This is of no real consequence, but it is still driving me crazy.

Does anyone know the reason for this behavior? Does anyone have a fix?

Please help save my sanity.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an add-in causing this issue, as the add-in might add its own commands or ribbon tabs to the ribbon. You may try testing this in Outlook safe mode to see whether the issue persists. Press Win+R to open Run box, type: ***outlook /safe*** and press Enter.

Besides, we can also edit the following registry to

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Common\Toolbars\Outlook

DWORD: QuickAccessToolbarStyleExplorer

Value: 28

(Where x.0 stands for the version of Outlook. Outlook 2016 is 16.0; Outlook 2013 is 15.0; Outlook 2010 is 14.0)

Comment: Running in safe mode had no effect, outside of Outlook forgetting my password. Are you sure about the registry key? Remember that I am trying to effect the ribbon, not the Quick Access Toolbar (top left on the title bar).